# Is this a bug in SQL Server 2014 Express?

Tags: sql-server, wix, sql-server-2014-express

I have created a bootstraper-project with WiX 3.9 and installing - among others - SQL Server Express in unattended mode (like an installation per commandline).

In that installation, per command, I'm using quiet install and set the *INDICATEPROGRESS* to "True", so the user can watch the installation messages in a console window.

As long as I used SQL Server 2012 Express, all was fine, but now I changed to SQL Server 2014 Express.

The quiet installation works (faster than 2012) but the console window doesn't appear. I took a look at the MSDN site to see, if the parameters have changed, But they are all the same as before.

Can this maybe be a bug in SQL Server 2014 Express?

Comment: Does progress appear if you run the line from a command prompt?

Comment: No it doesn't appear, even when i start it from the command prompt like that:

SQLEXPR_x64_DEU.exe /Q /ACTION="Install" /INDICATEPROGRESS="True" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ENU="False" /UpdateEnabled="True" /FEATURES="SQLENGINE,LOCALDB,FULLTEXT,BOL" /UpdateSource="MU" /HELP="False" /INSTANCENAME="SQLEXPRESS" /INSTANCEID="SQLEXPRESS" ...